# Does using asset catalogs work for all images in app or just icon/launch images

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, retina, asset-catalog

I'm creating a iPad app that will ship with a lot of png images for use IN APP. I'm trying to determine if using asset catalog with xcode is viable to support retina *and* regular 1024 res but not force both versions to be downloaded. Most of the information on asset catalogs seems to talk about only app icons and launch images so I'm curious if it works fine for all app images.

My question is not only will the catalog work to make sure both versions of all images are not downloaded. But is it worth the work or should we just only include retina and let the app downscale the images for older ipads(which I know can be slow).

There will be around 20-40 png images over a background most of the time though there's not much active animation at all.

Comment: Currently anything you put in your asset catalog will be included in your app bundle and downloaded even for devices that won't be using some of those resources. iOS 9 is introducing app slicing which will create different variants of your app bundle with different subsets of your assets based on device type and screen resolution so unused resources won't be downloaded.

Comment: So that would work for only devices which are upgraded to iOS 9 right? I guess that's acceptable. Or do you think providing only retina resolution images and forcing non-retina devices to auto-scale would be fine? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use an asset catalog to store your png images. In iOS 9 apple implemented the new feature "app slicing". Sliced apps are supported on the latest iTunes and on devices running iOS 9.0+. You upload your app with all image resolutions and the App Store creates individual app variants from the archive for each device (retina, non retina etc.)

Take a look at [developer.apple.com - AppThinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

Comment: Have the same question as I asked the commenter. Would you suggest including both 1x and retina images even though at the moment(and for older pads in the future) it will download twice the assets unnecessarily. The trade-off I'm assuming is older ipads will run better but all pads will download more.

Comment: just adding that it's around 144mb of tga images atm which will be transferred to png soon. Not sure what the final size of both sets(1x&2x) of images will but but that may give you an idea.